# Ext js aligning the text field input box

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I have a fiddle, in the header trigger menu, there is a text field box called Name:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/161n

I want this input box to move all the way to the left, right next to the text Name:

[image]

Now I want it to look like:

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **labelwidth** property when configuring your **myT2** textfield.  By default all labels have 100px width.

```
xtype: 'textfield',
name: 'name',
fieldLabel: 'Name',
id: 'myT2',
labelWidth: '50px',
```

[ExJS Documentation](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.Labelable.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! another quick question, how to decrease the width of that text box? , just set the width property of myT2?